# How to make some part of text clickable and some part having different text color in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to make some portion of text of different color and clickable

Here is my code:

```
<Text style = {styles.term_service}>By signing up, you agree to Terms of Service and Privacy Policy.</Text>
```

I want to make Terms of Service and Privacy Policy clickable and have different color.

Answer (score 37):

you can use nested text [doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/text.html#nested-text) also `Text` accept `onPress` [doc](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/text.html#onpress)

```
<Text style = {styles.term_service}>By signing up, you agree to Terms of Service and <Text onPress={()=> someAction()} style = {{ color: '#fff' }}>Privacy Policy.</Text></Text>
```

Comment: the inner text being clicked is not working for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the onPress prop in the text component and use an arrow function to navigate to the terms and policy page.

Pass each one of them in a different text component and then make the style row style.

```js
<View 
style={styles.termsContainer}>
    <Text style = {styles.term_service}>By signing up, you agree to </Text>
    
    <Text  onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TermsAndConditions")}
    style={styles.terms_text}>Terms of Service and Privacy Policy.</Text>
    
    </View>
```

in the styles of the view
make the flexDirection:"row"
now the text will be next to each other